# Difference between AcceptAsync and other method (TcpClient)

Tags: c#

I am using await method in my function and and AcceptAsync in my TcpClient.

( TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync(); )

My question is:

Will i have problems with that? I see on forums that i can use Tasks or BeginAccept + CallBack method, but my code works perfectly with that right now.

Thnx for the answers!

Comment: Those are different code 'styles'. I prefer Task for UI applications and async for non UI applications.

Comment: It is a non UI app. I read in comments that client is awaiting all the time and i will have problem with that in the future. So do i have to change it? What do you think?

Comment: I think, Tasks use async in the back. So there won't be much difference. If you have limited clients (like max 5), I would use a thread per connection. Else I would use async.

Comment: I think the power of tasks come to it rights with wpf (dispather).

Comment: BeginAccept + Callback is an old way to handle async jobs. await+async uses Tasks for returning types.

Comment: Thnx for the answers.i have unlimited clients, because my app come accross every time a client makes a phone call to my company, so i dont have a specific number. That is why i use async and await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will i have problems with that?

No. I would, however, strongly recommend that you use SignalR if *at all* possible. Raw sockets have tons of obscure pitfalls and require extremely complex code to use correctly.

> I see on forums that i can use Tasks or BeginAccept + CallBack method, but my code works perfectly with that right now.

Your code is already using tasks. Specifically, it's using the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx). The `BeginAccept`/`EndAccept` style is called the [Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx). If possible, prefer TAP over APM because it is easier to use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!